# Conflicting user defined class name with inbuilt class name - C#

Tags: c#, namespaces, name-collision, name-conflict

I have the following code, where I am using the inbuilt C# `Stack` class in my own user defined `Stack1` class.
Everything works well with this user defined nomenclature. But, as soon as I change all references of my user defined `Stack1` class, and call it as a `Stack` class - the compiler gets confused, and the C# inbuilt `Stack` classes that I am using inside my `user defined Stack class` no longer correspond to the inbuilt `Systems.Collections.Stack` class. But, fall back to the user defined `StackHavingPopPushAndMinO1_2.Stack` class.
Do you know why this is happening, and is there any way I can keep my user defined Stack class name as `Stack` and still use the inbuilt `Systems.Collections.Stack` class inside it?

Please see: I already solved the issue by using the `System.Collections.Generic.Stack<int>` classes inside my user defined `Stack` class. But my intention here is that I don't want to change the name of my user defined `Stack` class - and still use the inbuilt `Systems.Collection.Stack` class inside it.

Please see: I also created an alias for `System.Collections` and appended it to the inbuild `Stack` classes I am using. But I was just wondering if there is some other way I can use my user defined `Stack` class which has the inbuilt `Systems.Collections.Stack`classes in it.

Following is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackHavingPopPushAndMinO1_2
{
    class Stack1
    {
        Stack mainStack = new Stack();
        Stack supportingStack = new Stack();

        public void Push(int value)
        {
            mainStack.Push(value);
            if(supportingStack.Count==0 || value <= (int) supportingStack.Peek())
            {
                supportingStack.Push(value);
            }
        }

        public int Pop()
        {
            int value = -1;
            if(mainStack.Count>0)
            {
                value = (int) mainStack.Pop();
                if (value == (int) supportingStack.Peek())
                    supportingStack.Pop();
            }
            return value;
        }

        public int Min()
        {
            if (supportingStack.Count > 0)
                return (int) supportingStack.Peek();
            return -1;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stack1 stack = new Stack1();
            stack.Push(60);
            stack.Push(10);
            stack.Push(50);
            Console.WriteLine(stack.Min());
            stack.Push(80);
            stack.Push(9);
            stack.Push(11);
            Console.WriteLine(stack.Min());
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine with the user defined class `Stack1`. But, as soon as I change the name of `Stack1` to `Stack`, the compiler gets confused, and we get errors due to name conflict. Any light on this will be greatly helpful. Why does not the C# Compiler know the difference between the user defined `Stack` class, and the inbuilt `Stack` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does not the C# Compiler know the difference between the user defined Stack class, and the inbuilt Stack class?

How would you expect it to do so? When it encounters a declaration of a variable like this:

```cs
Stack stack = null;
```

... which class should that refer to? I suspect that in some cases you'd want that to refer to `StackHavingPopPushAndMinO1_2.Stack`, and in other cases you'd want it to refer to `System.Collections.Stack`. The C# compiler follows very strict name lookup rules to determine the meaning of a name. You can find those rules in the C# specification, and I suspect that you'd be hard-pressed to design *better* rules.

In particular, looking at your class, you have:

```cs
class Stack // After renaming
{
    Stack mainStack = new Stack();
    ...
```

Presumably, you want the type of `mainStack` to be `System.Collections.Stack`, otherwise you'll end up with infinite recursion - but what rules would you expect to determine that?

Your options are:

- Avoid the naming collision, which is generally the best approach
- Use aliases to be explicit
- Use fully-qualified names, e.g. `System.Collections.Stack stack = null;` instead of just the unqualified name